# Pledge with different amounts

Tags: contributions, pledges, civipledge

My organisation thinking about handling donations (bulk import 100-200 donations per occasion). Since they would like to see the "deviation" - difference - from total pledges at the beginning of a year, it would be nice to be able to use the CiviCRM Pledges functions.

Using the `Import Contributions` function, I was able to import contributions - from a CSV file - as pledges, but only if the total amount paid matches the pre-set, calculated amount. If the two amounts do not match, the import throws an error and the line is not read.

How can I import the pledge even if the imported amount is different from the pre-calculated amount?